# Big request queue times for Rails app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, heroku

We're seeing issues with our Rails app on Heroku under load where request queueing (as reported by New Relic) rises dramatically, despite CPU utilization being well under 100% and memory usage being well within the dynos' capacity.

The places I've thought to look for issues at this point are resources contention (e.g database connections) and blocking awaiting responses from external services.

I'm looking for help with how to approach sorting the issue out.  Aside from the two things I've mentioned what else would you be looking for?  What tools would you use to get at the data and make sense of it?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What kind of activity are you receiving (concurrent users)?  Any errors in log files?

Comment: For instance, during a load test earlier today, running  for 10 minutes at 600 rpm (100 users making requests every 10 secs), cpu usage reached only 52%, while request queueing reached 3260 ms per request out a total of 4000 ms per request including middleware, Ruby, and pg.  105 of the responses got 503s.  There were no errors in the logs, aside from those.

Comment: This is going to sound very vague, but it could be any number of things.  As you may know, 503's can come from poor server specs, too many concurrent connections, long running tasks... but those are some places to start.  You didn't specify your server platform, but (assuming there's no code-related issues) you may want to start searching for issues specific to the OS.

Comment: Database connections (too small a pool and requests will block), long running queries, session stores (i.e. too small a Redis pool), etc. Anything where your application is reaching out to other services often blocks as the requests increase. You should note what dyno sizes and DB plan(s) you are using.

Comment: Thanks guys.  

This application is running on puma single-threaded, with 12 workers on a single 2x dyno (so we can't blame the Heroku router) with a pool of 15 connections to a hobby-dev postgres dyno.  We are going to a Standard0, so that might help.

Comment: I'm going to have to look into the Redis connection thing.  We're using RedisCloud and I haven't seen anything in the docs about configuring a connection pool, so I assume that as it stands there's probably only 1 connection per worker.

Comment: Is it reasonable to conclude that with Heroku's router out of the question (since we only have one web dyno) the growing request queue must be due almost exclusively to waiting on puma workers, or is there still some possibility of problems upstream from there?

Comment: Did you find the bottleneck? We recently experienced the same and we did not reach CPU, memory or connection limit.

Comment: I'm also curious to hear if/how you've solved this as I'm experiencing a similar problem after having just scaled up from ~1rpm to ~100rpm and I have an identical setup.

Answer (score 0):

WebBrick is the default for Rails apps and it is a single threaded server meaning that any requests that come from users with poor connections will likely make your requests queue up waiting for that user with the slow connection to download their request. If you're not using Puma or Phusion Passenger you're likely going to continue to see this problem.

Comment: See this link for reference:
https://www.speedshop.co/2015/07/29/scaling-ruby-apps-to-1000-rpm.html